Seeking Advice on Authorship Dispute
My supervisor, who had no contribution to my thesis work, instructed me to write a paper from it for clearance. I provided a draft, but he submitted it to a conference with himself as the first author without informing me. Today, I received an email to authenticate my authorship. I wish to pursue higher studies on this topic and plan to apply for Fall 2025, where being the first author would greatly benefit me. What should I do?

Kindly give me guidelines.

have you talked to your supervisor about it?

what do you mean by no contribution?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/169853/advisor-wants-to-put-his-name-on-my-paper-when-i-did-all-the-work-and-found-the

First, you should try to resolve this with your supervisor, just to eliminate any possibility of misunderstanding. If the situation turns out to be unethical, aka premeditated, then you can contact the conference organizers and submit your thesis as proof, since the thesis should contain all the content, your name, and your supervisor's name.

I want to clarify the point about having it as a misunderstanding. I once heard a story in my department where this sometimes happens when the supervisor formats the article, like rewriting or reformatting it to fit the standard using their template, then the name of the author got changed and overlooked. Of course, this is very unlikely, but it's worth considering as it could possibly prevent a falling out with a potential partner in your academic career.
